# How to remove attribute or replace attribute value using XSL/XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a following in my XML file:

```
  <Hits>
    <Hit status="good">     
      <batter ref="4">Sample Text 1</batter>
      <contexts ref="5">Sample Text 2</contexts>
    </Hit>
    <Hit status="bad">
      <batter ref="7">Sample Text 3</batter>
      <contexts ref="" />
    </Hit>
  </Hits>
```

I am trying to produce a XSL that will remove the `ref` attribute in any element or just replace the `ref` attribute's value with something hardcoded like `"XXX"`.  I would prefer to find and remove the `ref` attribute as my first option.

Below is the XSL I am working with, but it doesn't actually remove the attributes in question:

```
<xsl:template match="Hit">
   <xsl:copy-of select="." />
   <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>



<xsl:template match="/Hit/batter/@ref">
        <xsl:attribute name="ref">
            <xsl:value-of select="$mycolor"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  What exactly does not work?

Comment: @J0e3gan - My original xsl did not replace the attribute ref value.

The solution provided by michael.hor257k works but I didn't include all elements of the XML.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyRecords>
  <A>Sample Text A</A><B>Sample Text B</B><C>Sample Text C</C>
  <D><E id="name">Name</E><E id="color">Color</E></D>
<Hits>
    <Hit status="good"><batter ref="4">Sample Text 1</batter><contexts ref="5">Sample Text 2</contexts></Hit>
    <Hit status="bad"><batter ref="7">Sample Text 3</batter><contexts ref="" /></Hit>
  </Hits>
</MyRecords>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to produce a xsl that will ... replace the attribute ref
>   value with something hardcoded

The main problem with your approach is that your second template is never applied, because your first template does not apply any templates.

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@ref">
    <xsl:attribute name="ref">place a hard-coded value here</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly for the XML I originally provided. But how will not work if I had more XML elements:


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyRecords>
  <A>Sample Text A</A>
  <B>Sample Text B</B>
  <C>Sample Text C</C>
  <D>
    <E id="name">Name</E>
    <E id="color">Color</E>
 </D>
<Hits>
    <Hit status="good">     
      <batter ref="4">Sample Text 1</batter>
      <contexts ref="5">Sample Text 2</contexts>
    </Hit>
    <Hit status="bad">
      <batter ref="7">Sample Text 3</batter>
      <contexts ref="" />
    </Hit>
  </Hits>
</MyRecords>

Comment: @VeeBot The code above will reproduce **any** XML document *as is* without any changes - except for the `ref` attribute (on any element). If that's not what you want, please edit your question and explain.